# Whenever a record is created in a table, I want a record with the same PK to be created in another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to DB, this must be very basic. Basically I have 2 tables, say customers and addresses for example. Whenever a new customer is created (that table has a PK that is an ID), I want that same ID to be created on the other table.

I've already created a FK on the addresses table, but I have no idea how to configure the DB so that a record will be created automatically. Can the DB engine do that or should that be done on the client program?

Comment: This begs the question: why are there two tables? Why not just put it in the same table?

Comment: You made me think... I was trying to adapt the DB layer to the UI level. Was able to fix the data display layer, which makes much more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This give the ability to have at least one detail item on your master table and then if you want add more. This functionality is very useful for data entry and you can perform more in less time and less effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a trigger like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER customer_insert AFTER INSERT ON customers  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO addresses(Customer_ID,AnotherColumnExample)  
         VALUES(NEW.ID,'Stuff for the extra column');  
END;
```